# Why separate declaration from export of variables in bash scripts?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script like

```
#!/bin/bash
DATABASE_NAME=my_database
export DATABASE_NAME
run_some_other_command
```

They first declare the variable and set it to a value, then in a separate line, they export it. Personally, I like to just do it in one line like:

```
export DATABASE_NAME=my_database
```

Is there some style rule against this? I've seen the declaration and export be separated by others, but never knew why.

If it helps, this script runs on Linux Mint, but could run on other Linux's or even a Mac.

Comment: From what I know, separating them makes it POSIX compatible

Comment: Since you're using Bash don't worry about it.

Comment: @Fravadona POSIX allows assignments in `export` commands. Some older shell may not have, which may have led to a belief that `export` must still be done separately from assignment.

Comment: A lot of people also use `export` even when it isn't needed; I wouldn't take a random sample of `bash` scripts in the wild as indicative of anything resembling good practice.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for correcting a misconception of mine. I came up with this conclusion by looking at the default `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` in some Linux distros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `export` is a command; when assignment comes from a command or sub-shell output, its own return code will override/mask the return code of the assigning command:

```sh
# the return-code of the getDBName function call
# is masked by the export command/statement
export DATABASE_NAME=$(getDBName)
```

```sh
# Separate export
export DATABASE_NAME

# Allow capture and use of the getDBName return code
if ! DATABASE_NAME=$(getDBName)
then printf 'Failed getDBName with RC=%d\n' "$?" >&2
fi
```